# How to use LINQ on this query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want to convert the `IEnumerable<Target>`  of :

```
public class Target
{
        public Frame BaseFrame;

        public Rect[] rects;
}
```

To `IEnumerable<foo>` of :

```
public class foo
{
      public Frame BaseFrame;
      public Rect rect;
}
```

e.g. expand the `Rect[]` array,  `IEnumerable<Target>` to `IEnumerable<foo>`, how to write LINQ on this function?

example:

sequence of Target:

```
t1(rects.Count==2), t2(rects.Count==3)
```

sequece of foo (after conversion):

```
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5
```

Comment: @KennyTM, yes, exactly in the expaned class.

Comment: If `rects` contain 4 elements, there should be 4 `foo`'s enumerable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var q = from t in targets
        from r in t.Rects
        select new foo
        {
          BaseFrame = t.BaseFrame,
          Rect = r
        };
```